# pygame won't import and the shell says 'no module named pygame'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

On my raspberry pi I imported pygame using sudo apt-get install pygame but the shell says:  'no module named pygame.' why?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

error in line 1 of car_race.py
no module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: What happens when you do `dpkg -l | grep pygame` from the shell?

Comment: `import sys; sys.path` tells you where import looks for pygame.  If it is not on any of the directories listed, import fails.

Comment: Thanks Terry ill do that

Answer (score 1):

Go to the command prompt and enter `pip install pygame`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, hold: windows+R and then type in 'cmd' and enter. This will open up the command prompt. Type in:

```
pip install pygame
```

On Mac: hold: cmd+space and then type in 'terminal' and enter. This will open up the terminal. Type in:

```
python -m install pygame
```

and that should work.

Comment: If you already have pygame installed, it will say:
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\charl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)

if you made a typo, it will say:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 'what you typed in'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 'what you typed in'

otherwize, It should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the terminal snippets should be run at the command line. Open the terminal on Windows by pressing Windows, typing "cmd", and then presseing enter. Alternatively on Windows, press Win+R, then type "cmd", and press enter. On macOS, open the terminal by pressing Cmd+Space, then typing "terminal", and pressing enter.

Try installing `python3-pygame` or `python3-pygame-sdl2` instead of just `pygame`. These packages contain pygame as well. If that doesn't work, try using `pip`, i.e. `pip3 install pygame` (or `pip install pygame` on Windows.)

Pip (which is a recursive acronym, meaning either Pip Installs Packages or Pip Installs Python), is helpful for installing python packages. It should come with python, but if it isn't then install it on Raspberry Pi (Linux) with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

### Mac / Linux / Raspberry Pi

Try these:

`sudo apt install python3-pygame`

`sudo apt install python3-pygame-sdl2`

If those don't work, use

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

then

`pip3 install pygame`

### Windows

Try `pip install pygame`.
If that doesn't work, install pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
py get-pip.py
```

Then, when `pip` is installed, run `pip install pygame` again.